# Rails logic works in view but not controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, controller

I have the following loop in my view to display all divisions in a given tournament. When I try to replicate the logic in the controller, then pass the variable to the view, I and "undefined methods" error. Any help with what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Models

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :divisions
end
class Division < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tournaments
end
```

WORKING Controller & View
Controller

```
 def index
    @tournaments = Tournament.all
 end
```

View

```
<% tournament.divisions.ids.each do |tdi| %>
  <%= Division.find(tdi).name %> 
<% end %>
```

NOT WORKING Controller & View
Controller

```
 def index
    @tournaments = Tournament.all
    @tournaments.divisions.ids.each do |tdi|
      @divisions = Division.find(tdi).name
    end
  end
```

View

```
<%= @divisions %>
```

When I try the second (and I'm sure more correct) implementation, I get a **"undefined method `divisions'"** error for the following line in the index method:

```
@tournaments.divisions.ids.each do |tdi|
```

Comment: Most probably the @divisions is inside the each loop. The scope is just inside that loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `@tournaments = Tournament.all` this line returns a list of `tournament` objects. So, in the second line you cannot relate a list of object with any kind of association. You have to Iterate through the `@tournaments` and then find the `divisions` for each tournament.

```
 def index
    @tournaments = Tournament.all
    # you can also eager load the tournamnets
    # @tournaments = Tournament.includes(:divisions)   
    @tournaments.each do |tournament|
         tournament.divisions.ids.each do |tdi|
            @divisions = Division.find(tdi).name
         end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think the error is telling you is that the method ids is not a method of divisions. Yo would have to define that method as scope in your Division model.

```
scope :ids, -> { pluck(:id) }
```

Another thing is that I don't understand why are you trying to do something like this:

```
<% tournament.divisions.ids.each do |tdi| %>
  <%= Division.find(tdi).name %> 
<% end %>
```

when you can just simply do this:

```
<% tournament.divisions.each do |tdi| %>
  <%= tdi.name %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, in the 2nd case you are calling association on collection, You need to do this, in controller, ultimately you need all the division names, here you also have `n + 1` query problem so to solve that

```
def index
  @tournaments = Tournament.includes(:divisions)
end
```

In view

```
@tournaments.each do |tournament|
  tournament.divisions.each do |division|
    <%= division.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!